# Inserting multiple values into a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to run this command but need to insert new two variables for every time I run this command. I think the right approach is to loop through a dictionary and add in the two variables each loop. Ive never looped through a dictionary where there were multiple values per key. Let me know if there are any other approaches to consider.

```
sample_dict = {key0: ['source0','parameter0'],
               key1: ['source1','parameter1'],
               key2: ['source2','parameter2'],
               key3: ['source3','parameter3']}


for values in sample_dict:

  example_cmd = "set -a; source ~/.bash_profile; python3 $path/file.py \
  --dbtype db --config-dir $CONFIG_DIR \
  --db-conn-config-file db.conf \
  --sqlfile $path/{source} \
  --params {parameter}"

  example_cmd
```

Comment: Use `for key, values in sample_dict` where values is the list of values.

Comment: You're missing the `f` before the f-string.

Comment: What are `source` and `parameter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but iterating through a dictionary in the way you did will actually iterate over the keys, not the values. To iterate over just values, you can use:

```py
for value in sample_dict.values():
    ...
```

To iterate over both in pairs, use:

```py
for key, value in sample_dict.items():
   ...
```

In your specific case, you could do something like:

```py
for source, parameter in sample_dict.values():
   ...
```

This will iterate only over the values (which are lists in your case) and expand each list into the `source` and `parameter` variables, as each list has exactly two elements. You have to be careful not to have fewer than 2 items in each list in the dict, as it will lead to a runtime error otherwise.

Also, note that both the `values()` and `items()` methods return an iterator (generator), not a list.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through the keys, not the values. You need to loop through `sample_dict.values()`.

Then you can use spread assignment to set the `source` and `parameter` variables to the two elements of each list.

If you're substituting variables with `{variable}` you need to use an f-string.

```
for source, parameter in sample_dict.values():
    example_cmd = f"set -a; source ~/.bash_profile; python3 $path/file.py \
  --dbtype db --config-dir $CONFIG_DIR \
  --db-conn-config-file db.conf \
  --sqlfile $path/{source} \
  --params {parameter}"
```